# How to terminate forEachObject loop?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

This question belongs to fabricJS and canvas. In following case check is there any object which property true (`obj.background == true`). There can be several images on canvas. After the first object detection, I want to terminate the loop. How I do this? I ave used `return false;` but does not work. Here is the function.

```
    canvas.forEachObject(function(obj){
        if(obj.isType('image') && obj.hasOwnProperty('background')){
            if(!obj.background == true){
                alert("true");
                return false;
            } 
        }
    });
```

Comment: You can have a `flag` inside it .. But if you want to terminate a loop, go with the `for-loop...break;`

Comment: Do you tried `continue n;`?

Comment: Likely, `forEachObject` is not designed to terminate the loop before each object is performed against the `function(obj)`. You may want to consider using normal for-loop.

Comment: Looking at the source code, it's clear that there is no way to stop the iteration untimely: http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.js.html#line264 .

Comment: @nagazi - can't use `continue n;` inside `forEachObject`

Comment: Decided to move to the `for-loop` and it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Now i haven't used FabricJS (awaiting a spam of down-votes already) looking at the source there is a `getObjects()` method. What this does is return an array of objects instead of a custom iterator like `forEachObject()`.

So with that you could use all the normal array itteration methods like `forEach()`, `some()`, `every()` etc which will allow you to do what you wish.

So my understanding is you want to check if the object is an image and if its background property is true, and abort the loop on the first occurrence? This should do it.

```
canvas
    .getObjects()
    .some(obj => {
        if (obj.isType('image') && obj.hasOwnProperty('background') && obj.background === true) {
            console.log('Aww shucks, you found me.');
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Obviously this is pseudo code.
Essentially it will loop all objects and abort if your return `true`. If any element does return `true` the return value from `some` will also be `true`.

---

EDIT after Michał Dopieralski comment.

I overlooked the fact `getObjects` can be passed a type and will filter the results for you. So using that things get even simpler.

```
canvas
    .getObjects('image')
    .some(obj => {
        if (obj.background === true) {
            console.log('Aww shucks, you found me.');
            return true;
        }
    });
```

[array some docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

[fabricjs getObjects source](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.js.html#line273)

---

EDIT:
On a side note the `hasOwnProperty` check shouldn't be required i don't think. So long as `obj` is defined then accessing a property of it that doesn't exist will return `undefined`. Which will fail the `=== true` check.

Comment: And whatsmore you can pass an object type to getObjects() and get an array of objects which you need. For example canvas.getObjects('image') gives you an array of object.type === 'image' :-)